# Why does Chrome 59-Beta with real Headless option fail in use with Protractor?

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome, protractor, travis-ci

I wanted to use the newest Chrome 59-Beta with the `--headless` Option to test our Angular Project (github .com/h-da/geli).

I was able to use `karma` with the new GC-Beta, but I wasn't able to run `protractor` with the new GC-Beta. I have tried to run protractor on Jenkins and on my local vagrant machine, both gave me the same error:

```
    [17:13:12] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
    [17:14:12] E/launcher - chrome not reachable
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-51-generic x86_64)
    [17:14:12] E/launcher - WebDriverError: chrome not reachable (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-51-generic x86_64)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
    From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
        at Function.createSession (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
        at Function.createSession (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
        at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.ts:90:25)
        at Runner.createBrowser (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:225:39)
        at q.then.then (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:391:27)
        at _fulfilled (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
        at /home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
        at runSingle (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
        at flush (/home/travis/build/[secure]/geli/app/webFrontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    [17:14:12] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

You can see the Jenkins Build here: travis-ci .org/khase/geli/builds/232136348 and the Code fron that Build is here: https://github.com/khase/geli/tree/1fe73b4aac9b and the protractor file is here https://github.com/khase/geli/blob/1fe73b4aac9b5c8c0b39b93a8fe40283dd3a92f7/app/webFrontend/protractor.conf.js

Now my question: Why do I get the `chrome not reachable`?

Thank you guys a lot :)

PS: We forked our real Project to test the CI stuff => /khase/geli

Answer (score 0):

Try using a later chromedriver. These errors usually indicates a version mismatch between chrome and chromedriver. Per your log you are using `chromedriver=2.29.461571` which I believe is too old for Chrome 59.

You can check available versions at http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (which nowadays also lists supported chrome versions). Additionally you can use [webdriver-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager) to fetch latest/specific versions automatically, typically from your CI pipeline.